# Generating a word document using a Json Array in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, file

I have a Json array of object as follows

```
[{name: test1, age:20},{name: test2, age:23},{name: test3, age:30}]
```

I want to print these values to a table in Microsoft word document. In another way, I want to generate a word document with above values displayed in a table using angularjs. How can I proceed?

Comment: Have you looked at any libraries for generating a Word document on npm?

Comment: I Googled several libraries such as html-docx-js, docx.js. I wanted to know if there is any otherway other than using these libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could achieve this without using any third party libraries as follows. Here I am displaying the values in a HTML table and that table is converted into a word document.

```
<script>
$scope.arrayValFunc = function()
{
$scope.arrayVal =[];
//some code to assign values to the json array

}

$scope.downloadWordDoc = Export2Doc(element, filename = ''){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById(element).innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });

    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);

    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';

    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }

    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}

</script>

<html>
<div id="divOne">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="record in arrayVal">
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<tr>
<td>{{record.name}}</td>
<td>{{record.age}}</td>
</tr>
</div>
<input type="submit" ng-click="downloadWordDoc('divOne');"/>
</html>
```